# Batch FOR Loop to compress Files not Containing a String

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using html/js minifier to minify my files the dos commands works fine. I need to change this batch command to minify files which the file names not contain string .min

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%F in ('dir /b /a-d * ^| find /v /i "min"') do (



if /I %%~xF == .php html-minifier %%~dpnF%%~xF --minify-js -o %%~dpnF.min%%~xF

if /I %%~xF == .html html-minifier %%~dpnF%%~xF --minify-js -o %%~dpnF.min%%~xF

if /I %%~xF == .js uglifyjs %%~dpnF%%~xF -o %%~dpnF.min%%~xF



)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are including `.min` before the extension of the files when processing it, you can retrieve the name of the file and from this string check the extension

```
real file name                         testfile.min.js
file name without extension (%%~nF)    testfile.min
     includes its own extension                ^^^^
```

So, you can process the file name with an additional `for` command

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for /r %%F in (
        *.php *.html *.js
    ) do for %%A in ("%%~nF") do if /i not "%%~xA"==".min" (
        if /I "%%~xF"==".php"  html-minifier "%%~fF" --minify-js -o "%%~dpnF.min%%~xF"
        if /I "%%~xF"==".html" html-minifier "%%~fF" --minify-js -o "%%~dpnF.min%%~xF"
        if /I "%%~xF"==".js"   uglifyjs      "%%~fF"             -o "%%~dpnF.min%%~xF"
    )
```

Comment: I need a updation for this code. this code going through out all folders and sub folders I need to restrict it. Should go into selected folders...